# Default Stock Status & Quantity | Default Swatch Images

Tags: magento2.3

Roadblocks for newbies are endless in Magento 2 and we are not exceptions. At this moment, we are stuck in the following problems. Any suggestions are welcome.

- After importing each product using Webkul Aliexpress Importer, we are
  setting stock status and quantity manually since by default there is
  "out of stock" in stock status and "0" in quantity. The developer
  didn't help much. Is there any way to set them by default "In Stock"
  and with some quantity?

  - While importing products with swatch images, they appear in dropdown    box on our website. Any suggestions how to set swatch by
    default?

Answer (score 0):

1. for setting stock status and quantity

   a.) create a csv file like this

   [image]

   b.) go to system->import -> select product from import setting -> choose add/updae from import behaviour and import ...
2. For changing swatch dropdown box go to -> store ->attribute ->product . find your attrbute .here you will find **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner**
   from here you can change the dropdown to swatches

[image]

hope it helps .